# didUpdateToLocation not called after stopping location updates and starting it again

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

I have a scenario where i search for the current location.Once the current location search begins i use "startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges" i get didUpdateToLocation delegate called and i get a location value.

After the search is over i use "stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges" to turn off the GPS.

My problem is i may to the surrent location search after some time,when its done that is when i again start searching for current location after sometime GPS turns on but "didUpdateToLocation" is not called.

I am doing all these in a view controller.

I have initialized the location manager and have set the desiredAccuracy to "kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters" and distanceFilter to "10.0f".

Why i am not able to call "didUpdateToLocation" delegate on stooping the location updates and starting it again.

Please any body help me...

Expecting for a positive response from any of you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use startUpdatingLocation instead of startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges. startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges calls didUpdateToLocation only when location is significantly changed.

```
if (locationManager == nill)
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```